# yes is 91 lines long

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source

`yes`, from coreutils, is [91 lines long](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/yes.c?id=8e93dc629727140e950a709008f9a17ca461af63). Many of them are comments, but that is still **WAY** too long.

Edit from September 2019: the source file grew over the past five years and is now 126 lines long.

Write a program that imitates `yes`:

- outputting to `stdout` an infinite stream of "y\n"'s
- there must be an option to stop it other than killing the process with `SIGKILL`: but `SIGINT` and `SIGPIPE` are fine
- you are not allowed to use "y" or "\n" or their ASCII values (121, 0x79, 0171, 10, 0xA or 012)

Shortest answer wins.

Bonus:

- subtract 10 from your code length, if you can receive a phrase in `stdin` and print it out instead of "y" (but still including the line-break). The program [doesn't have to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/yes-is-91-lines-long/162321?noredirect=1#comment100392_42428) print `y` on an empty input.

Comment: For the bonus, should it still print `y` for empty STDIN?

Comment: "*you are not allowed to use "y" or "\n"*" -- should I read this as "You may not use `y` or `\n` inside of a string literal"?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Optionally.

Comment: @apsillers In the source code, nothing that evaluates to y or \n. Not in a literal, not as a constant, not as a variable name. Nothing.

Comment: @RamonSnir Wait, so I can just print empty lines for empty STDIN if I go for the bonus?

Comment: This is impossible in Java, without using `System`

Comment: @Ypnypn Here's my best guess: Perhaps a rule of thumb might be "if a source-code token has a `y` in it, you must be able to replace it with a synonymous token without a `y`." For example, if you have `System.out.print("y")`, you can do something like `Sstem = System` and `Sstem.out.print` would work fine (at least conceptually). By contrast, if you replace the literal  `"y"` with something else, you're not going to get the same result. I think this should probably clarified in the spec.

Comment: On a related note, GNU `true.c` is 80 lines long.

Comment: @Ypnypn It __is__ possible. There are more ways than one to get `System.out`.

Comment: @TheBestOne Indeed; I just solved this with reflection.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson On a similarly related note, false.c is 2 lines long.... ;_;

Comment: Is providing output in a different character encoding permissible (eg. using PETSCII rather than ASCII-1967)?

Comment: @RamonSnir Just to be sure, is my C# answer valid? It uses `System` (which I cannot get rid of, because it's the top namespace and everything is in it), but in your previous comment you said "nothing that evaluates to `y`". It does not evaluate to `y`. Is that answer valid?

Comment: @Ypnypn I just solved this without reflection.

Comment: the coreutils `yes` takes an optional argument on the command line, not `stdin`.

Comment: @RamonSnir and I started this after `git clone`ing `coreutils` and getting angry that `ls` is 8000 lines long. This post is all about getting candidates for replacing the "bloated" coreutils :)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Let me introduce you to [GNU Hello](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/)

Comment: @NateEldredge: I call foul though since that's an example program and not a standard utility. ;-)

Comment: @RamonSnir *"Nothing that evaluates to `y` or `\n`"* would make the challenge impossible. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I don't get GNU: Why would you possibly need a program which spams you with `y`s?

Comment: @MrLore: to pipe into other programs that might constantly ask for confirmation of the various things they are doing, so you dont have to sit there typing the `y`s yourself.

Comment: OMG there's no `\n` at the end of the file O_o that's horrible!

Comment: @mrl i regularly do `yes | sudo pacman -Syu` because i'm a terrible person

Comment: @undergroundmonorail the whole story started when I did `alias aurauy="yes | ( aura -Suy && aura -Auy )"` :)

Comment: There are lots of answers which use `121 + 1` to get `y`'s ascii code. Are those invalid? Can I have newlines outside string literals?

Comment: **Microsoft, 1 Steve Ballmer** — *developers, developers, developers, developers, ...*

Comment: How do you get to 91 from that page while counting comments? I see 130.

Comment: @FabianRöling This question is from 6 years ago. Back then it was 91 but since then the file grew up to 130 lines long.

Answer (score 38):

## CJam, 13 bytes - 10 = 3

```
l_'x)?{_oNo}h
```

You'll need to use [the Java interpreter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/) for this, because the online interpreter only returns once the program terminates.

You can abort the program with SIGINT (by pressing Ctrl-C). It will read a line from STDIN, and print that line, or `y` if the input was empty.

### Explanation

```
l             "Read line from STDIN.";
 _            "Duplicate.";
  'x          "Push character x.";
    )         "Increment to get y.";
     ?        "Ternary operator. Replaces line with y if it was empty.";
      {    }h "Repeat while true. Leaves condition on the stack, which is the output string.";
       _o     "Duplicate line and print.";
         No   "Push string with newline and print.";
```

After clarification of the OP, the following seems more to spec:

```
l{_o9c)o1}g
```

I'll wait with updating the submission until the OP replies to my comment, though.

Comment: I like that your program happens to match `/no/i`, considering what the challenge it.

Answer (score 23):

## Brainfuck - 38 bytes

```
++++++++++[>++++++++++++>+<<-]>+[.>.<]
```

It doesn't use 10 or 121, because `+-<>.,[]` are all the meaningful characters in the language anyway, but it does calculate them pretty naively (0+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=10, 10*12+1=121).

This probably depends on the interpreter, but it dies to `^C` on my machine.

## Brainfuck - (63-10)=53

```
++++++++++[>,]<<[[<]>>[[.>]<[<]>]]>[>++++++++++++>+<<-]>+[.>.<]
```

Comment: @fry I couldn't get it below 39 that way. I need 10 anyway, so I'm either adding 1 to 120 or subtracting 1 from 11, and it's shorter to do the former.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed after that you reused the 10, sorry :P

Comment: Instead of 10*12+1, why not 11*11? I think that could save you a char.

Comment: @pro I couldn't get it below 39 that way. I need 10 anyway, so I'm either adding 1 to 120 or subtracting 1 from 11, and it's shorter to do the former.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Ah, I see.

Answer (score 22):

## Python 3, 27 bytes

Works with at least CPython and Jython.

```
while 1:print(str(help)[1])
```

SIGINT stops it.

Comment: Make it python2 and you can shorten it to `while 1:print\`help\`[1]`.

Comment: Haha, nice. I completely forgot that there "used to" be a backtick operator in python :)

Comment: You could use `chr(11**2)` to save a few characters as well

Comment: @RamchandraApte You're not allowed to use `121`.

Comment: Why does this output y's?

Comment: @user1354557 "help" in python return: "Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object." so the second character (index 1) is "y"

Answer (score 19):

## Pyth, <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 6 bytes - 10 = <s>0</s> <s>-1</s> -4

```
#|zePG
```

I've been trying for ages to get one that I'm satisified with.  Basically converts to:

```
#      = while True
(implied print)
|      = or
z      = (automatically initialized from stdin)
ePG    = second-to-last lowercase letter = 'y'
```

Comment: The "z" variable is initialized from stdin, then the value is simply used after that.  Found a short way to get the ascii value without writing it explicitly.

Comment: Switched from "^11 2" to "^hT2" to save a character.

Comment: Hi swstephe, I'm excited to see another user of the language! A couple of golfs: `#` has equivalent functionality to `W1`, and `ePG` is a much shorter way to get the character `y` than `C^hT2`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll apply those changes.  Still new at this golf thing.  I like Pyth, but wish had a few more contextual functions and bit manipulation.

Answer (score 17):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang) 14 bytes

```
0978
]]/\++
!!
```

This is pretty straightforward, the '/\' device places two copies on its left and right, the right one is incremented by `++` and then falls off the board and is printed. The `]]` device pushes any marble to the right if STDIN is empty but lets the first byte on STDIN fall down if it isn't. This will then trigger the `!!` device, which exits the board. So this will print y\n until you enter anything on stdin.

This only works in the python interpreter.

Answer (score 13):

## C#, <s>81</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

Cannot compete with the other languages, but here it is anyway:

```c#
class A{static void Main(){for(;;)System.Console.WriteLine((char)('x'+1));}}
```

Can be killed with SIGINT by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

No bonus, because it would take more than 10 bytes to get it.

Comment: Can't you use `while(1)`? Saves two characters.

Comment: @toothbrush I have tried that, but that doesn't work in C#.

Comment: `for(;;)` [should](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx#code-snippet-4) work.

Comment: How about `class A{static void Main(string[]a){for(;;)System.Console.WriteLine(a[0]);}}`? It requires input, but it classifies as 63 bytes!

Comment: @core1024 Thanks, that works!

Comment: @toothbrush Good idea, but the question says that input should be given through STDIN, not command line.

Comment: @ProgramFOX I didn't realise.

Comment: How about 'x'+1 instead of 'G'+'2'? Two bytes less.

Comment: @tomsmeding That works, thanks!

Comment: For some reason, this code still has a `y` in it. Please examine `System`.

Comment: @TheBestOne That `System` cannot be removed. it is the top namespace in the .NET Framework, *all* classes/other namespaces are in it, so reflection won't help here. But not sure if it's invalid. See Ramon's comment: "nothing that evaluates to y or \n". This does not evaluate to `y`. I'm leaving a comment on the question to ask Ramon whether this is valid.

Answer (score 12):

### Java, 178

```
class C{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(char c='x'+1;;)((java.io.PrintStream)Class.forName("java.lang.S"+c+"stem").getField("out").get(null)).println(c);}}
```

Printing requires `System`, but the `y` character is forbidden. Hence, I had to use reflection.

Comment: [FileDescriptor.out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) is what I meant.

Comment: You can save a `;` by putting `char c='x'+1;` into the `for` loop declaration, so `for(char c='x'+1;;)` since you have an empty semicolon in there anyway

Comment: @corsiKa Good point.

Answer (score 10):

## Perl: 18 bytes - 10 = 8

The string is from STDIN.

```perl
$_=<>;{print;redo}
```

Comment: Does it print `y\n` repeatedly if it doesn't receive input from STDIN? If not, then it doesn't properly imitate `yes`.

Comment: @vurp0 `yes` does not take input from `STDIN` after all :)

Comment: It doesn't, but the code golf question here specified that if it doesn't receive input, it should repeatedly print `y\n`.

Comment: @vurp0 Where? Any program that reads from a stream will hang without input.

Comment: @vurp0 See the OP's comment on the question.

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, <s>30</s> <s>23</s> 18 bytes

```ruby
loop{puts ?x.succ}
```

Can be killed with SIGINT by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for sharing improvements!

Comment: `loop{puts [*?x..?z][1]}` – 23 chars, `loop{puts ?x.succ}` – 18 chars

Comment: @manatwork Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 26 bytes

```
{print chr$=*2+1,$/;redo}
```

### Custom input from argument (like `yes` actually works), 22 bytes-10=12

```
{print @ARGV,$/;redo}
```

### Custom input from stdin, 22 bytes-10=12

```
while(<>){print;redo}
```

Comment: @mar Nitz's program is only 14 bytes long and there's a very highly upvoted comment on your link that says it's chill for filenames to matter if you include them in the bytecount. This seems legit to me.

Comment: oh wait, i didn't see the "you can't use \"y\"" part of the question. nevermind this is bad

Comment: Right you are. Fixed it

Answer (score 8):

## Linux Bash - 19 bytes

This is probably cheating and subject to failure if you don't have /usr/bin/yes or have a /usr/bin/xes or /usr/bin/zes:

```
/usr/bin/[x-z]es $*
```

I think it meets the requirements, though maybe it's violating the "nothing that evaluates to y" rule. And perhaps  imitating `yes` by actually running `yes` is against the rules.

This could be optimized a bit (though less likely to work) to take it down to 11 bytes:

```
/*/*/?es $*
```

I couldn't figure out how to get the 10 point bonus by reading a string from stdin without adding more than 10 bytes to the code

Comment: ``/*/*/?es `line` ``, or ``/*/*/?es `head -n1` `` if you don't have `/usr/bin/line`.

Comment: Or `sed q` for `line`.

Answer (score 7):

### C, <s>64</s> <s>55</s> <s>53</s> <s>45</s> 40 - 10 = 30

`main(int c,int**a){for(;;)puts(a[c>1]);}`

I'm not hugely happy with this, as it requires the program to be named "y", and to be called with `y` only, so it has to be in $PATH, but hey, first codegolf :)

Alternative:

### C, 30 (+ 1 filename)

`main(){for(;;)puts(__FILE__);}`

Using the same technique as my esteemed colleague @Matt Windsor

- EDIT: turns out getting round the no \n character made it shorter
- EDIT2: "int" is shorter than "char"
- EDIT3: didn't need that variable at all
- EDIT4: a bit of slightly undefined behaviour never hurt anyone
- EDIT5: add alternative version

Answer (score 6):

## dc, 12

```
[30986Pdx]dx
```

Only outputs `y\n`.  Doesn't read from stdin, so no bonus.

30986 is 0x790A (i.e. "y\n").  The `P` command simply converts the number to base 256, and prints the corresponding character for each base 256 digit.

Comment: That's pretty clever, how does 30986 evaluate to `y\n`?

Comment: I knew about `P` but didn't know it can do more than one character at a time.

Answer (score 5):

### Common Lisp : (30-10) = **20**

```
(format t"~@{~a~%~:*~}"(read))
```

- `(read)` from input stream
- print to output stream: `(format t ... )`
- iterate over all `format` arguments (only one here) : `~@{ ... ~}`
- inside the loop, for each argument:

  - print argument `~A` followed by a newline `~%`
  - rewind *current element* to the previous one `~:*` (infinite loop)

You can break the loop with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, which signals an error with restart options (continue/abort).

Answer (score 5):

### **Linux Bash, 33-10 = 23**

```
read a; while :; do echo $a; done
```

Can be killed with SIGINT by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: You should read only one line and print the same line repeatedly. Your programs are not `yes` but `cat` programs.

Comment: My bad, I should not have tried it after à day of work.

Comment: How about `read a;for((;;));{ echo $a;}`

Answer (score 5):

## Rust, 52 chars

```
fn main(){loop{println!("{}",'Y'.to_lowercase())}}
```

There just isn't seemingly a nice way of computing `y` without being cheeky in Rust-- they've made too good a job of doing chars safely.  I:

- Can't supply a non-literal string to `println!`, so no tricks allowed there;
- Can't add 1 to `'x'`, because in Rust chars aren't numbers;
- Can't ROT13 (why doesn't Rust have ROT13 in its standard library!?);
- Can't easily do anything unsafe like dropping to C strings, converting from numbers to chars, etc without being incredibly verbose and going over 52c.

Nor is going for the code bonus worth it, because reading from `stdin` would require error handling =3

Much of the code reductions I could find involved doing increasingly rule-flouting things with the compiler environment:

## Rust, 44 chars (+ at least 1 char for filename)

```
fn main(){loop{println!("{:.1}", file!())}}
```

**Obsoleted by below.** This one probably doesn't count, as the name of the *source* file needs to begin with `y`.

## Edit: Rust, 36 chars (35 source, 1 filename)

```
fn main(){loop{println!(file!())}}
```

As above, but the file *has* to be called `y` (not `y.rs`, `y`).  Humorously, Rust will overwrite the source with the binary!  At least on my machine, the binary does work after that though.

## Rust, 37 chars (+ equivalent of `env K='y'` on your platform)

```
fn main(){loop{println!(env!("K"))}}
```

This one is even worse: you need to set the environment variable `K` to `y` at *compile time*.

**Edit**: if you set `K` to `y\n`, you could drop the `ln` in `println!`, for a grand total of <s>35 chars and</s> several facepalms:

```
fn main(){loop{print!(env!("K"))}}
```

Comment: Our usual policy for requiring certain file names or compiler flags is to simply include those in the byte count.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Fair enough.  Oddly enough, it would seem that rust isn't the best language for code golf >:P

Comment: You can add one to `x` in a fashion, but it's still not short: `(b'x' + 1) as char`

Answer (score 4):

### Commodore 64 Basic: <strike>14</strike> 13 bytes

```
1?C|(11↑2):R╭
```

As usual, I've made substitutions for characters in PETSCII that are not present in Unicode.  `|` is used to represent `SHIFT+H`, while `╭` represents `SHIFT+U`.  Note that this outputs ASCII 'y' (byte value 121) rather than a character that the default Commodore character set displays as 'y'.

BASIC is supposedly an easy-to-learn, English-like programming language.  Throw in the typing shortcuts present in many early dialects, and you get something that is shorter and less readable than Perl.

**EDIT**: In "shifted mode", this gets two bytes shorter, thanks to lowercase "y" being encoded at decimal value 89.  Using a non-ASCII character set to get around the "not allowed to use their ASCII values" rule might be cheating, though.

```
1?cH(89):rU
```

Comment: With all the  that exists in unicode, it seems surprising that the full character set used by the C64 wouldn't be in there somewhere.

Comment: @kasperd, Unicode's box-drawing characters come mostly from the IBM "DOS" set, and pass through the center of the character cell.  PETSCII has a much larger set, much of which uses the edges of the character cell.  U+2502 is probably a decent approximation of the vertical bar produced by `SHIFT+H`, but the pipe character is easier to type.  There's nothing corresponding to the "lines on the top and left edges" produced by `SHIFT+O".

Comment: Very good, but you could save one byte by replacing "Goto 1" by "Run" : "1?cH(89):rU"

Comment: @LeFauve, Thanks.  I've also applied it to the ASCII-emitting version.

Answer (score 4):

## [Fission](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission), 5 bytes

```
Rx+!N
```

This is fairly competitive for Fission. :)

Control flow starts with a `(1,0)` right-going atom at `R`. `x` sets the mass to `120`, and `+` increments it to give `(121,0)`. Then `!` prints the corresponding character (`y`) and `N` prints a newline. The source code wraps around at the edges, so the atom passes `R` again (which doesn't do anything now), `x` sets the mass to `120` again, `+` increments it and so on and so on...

Answer (score 3):

### AWK, 38 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(;;)printf("%c%c",60+61,5+5)}
```

Variant which will read the string on stdin: 14 bytes-10 = **4**

```
{for(;;)print}
```

But since it cannot do both (revert to "y" if no stdin is provided), I'm not sure it counts... :o)

Both can be exited with Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 27 bytes - 10 = 17

It's just @ProgramFOX's solution with the bonus (it took my 9 bytes to solve the bonus question).

```
loop{puts ARGV[0]||?x.succ}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 29 bytes

```
main=putStrLn[succ 'x']>>main
```

I believe this is stopped by both `SIGINT` and `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: suggestion: use `'\89'` instead of `succ 'x'`

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 21 bytes - 10 = 11

```
C1st?st[ltP[]ps0dx]dx
```

Note that the input needs to be wrapped in `[]`, e.g. `[no]`, because `?` is the only way to take input, which executes it as `dc` code.

Comment: You can use `C2` instead of `122`.  In fact I would argue that `122 1-` could be replaced with `C1` as `C1` is not explicitly banned in the question

Answer (score 3):

## C, 32 bytes

Requires little endian machine and compilation with -O2 (to avoid stack overflow).

```
a=11*11;main(){main(puts(&a));}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 31

Here is a Perl version that actually behaves like GNU `yes`, as far as I can tell:

```
{print "@ARGV"||chr 11**2;redo}
```

This works if it is okay to use perl's command line switches (`-l` for the newline), otherwise it would become 3 characters longer:

```
{print "@ARGV"||chr 11**2,$/;redo}
```

Comment: typo: is `-l` (not `-e`) the switch for the new line.

Comment: Also, the bonus is only if your script can read from the **stdin**. Yeah, I know that real **yes** does not read from the stdin, but from an argument, but that is the rule of the OP put; it has to be from stdin to have the bonus.

Comment: @chris-l fixed the type, thanks.  I also removed the claim regarding the bonus, but I will leave my answer as it is :-P

Comment: hehe sure, my own answer is like yours; it uses an argument instead of stdin. IMHO, the op should give the bonus to the ones who _actually_ do what the real **yes** does.

Answer (score 3):

#### Javascript, <strike>39</strike> 37 bytes

```js
for(;;)console.log(''+Function()[13])
```

#### Shorter alternative that only works in the browser, 36 bytes

```js
for(n=''+crypto;;)console.log(n[10])
```

#### Alternative without console.log, only works in NodeJS, <strike>58</strike> <strike>57</strike> 56 bytes

```js
for(n=''+Function()};;)process.stdout.write(n[13]+n[19])
```

Comment: Welcome to code golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thanks!

Comment: Your second answer uses `y` in `crypto`!

Comment: @Matthew Jensen Indeed it does!

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 27 − 10 = 17

```
param($s=$Host[1])for(){$s}
```

Might not work in Pash. A more robust alternative should be

```
param($s="$(gal gh*)"[2])for(){$s}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 42 bytes - 10 = 32

```
while 1 do print(...or('').char(90+31))end
```

## Lua, 49 bytes - 10 = 39

```
y=...or(string.char(60+61))while 1 do print(y)end
```

Both were tested with Lua 5.1.4 and can be killed with SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

Comment: Awesome! My mom writes in Lua, I've never seen it in the wild before. (*Hey mom! Guess what I saw!*)

Answer (score 2):

### Fortran, 28

```
do1;1 print'(A1)',11**2;end
```

Compile with `gfortran -ffree-form`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 - 10 = -5 bytes

Warning: relies on an undocumented and unsupported feature/bug.

```apl
⎕←⍣≢⍞
```

[Empty STDIN](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/yes-is-91-lines-long?page=2&tab=active#comment100350_42428) prints empty lines (not "y"), which [is allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/yes-is-91-lines-long?page=2&tab=active#comment100392_42428) and [has been suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@/@ob@qjtgmPehc/6lz0qHfe//@VAA)

`⎕` STDOUT with trailing newlines,

`←` gets

`⍣` repeatedly until

`≢` it differs from

`⍞` STDIN

i.e. never, but uninterruptible by pausing the thread.

Comment: Hmm. abusing bugs.. interesting.

Comment: @MatthewRoh Using, not abusing. The "feature" is using the operator `⍣` on assignment `←`, even though `←` isn't a real function proper, and thus not really eligible to be an operand. Still works through...

Answer (score 2):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 8 bytes

```
~W-1z'N~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/78uXNewSt2v7v9/AA)

Comment: i fixed it :)))

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `s`, 1-10 = -9 bytes

```
I
```

### Explanation

```
Flag: s % We have to read from STDIN :(
 P      % Newline-print
a       % the STDIN input
  I     % Forever
```

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 7 bytes

```
i12 1CE
```

### Explanation

```
i     E % Foreach from 1 to positive infinity:
         % (Implicit print a newline on each iteration)
 12 1    % Space does nothing. Basically just pushes 121.
     C  % Convert to a character, rendering 'y'
```

Comment: Never thought I'd see a negative score.

Comment: @PkmnQ I'm going to make this score `-9`.

Comment: Ties your other answer in Husk.

Comment: @a'_' You're not allowed to use `12 1`: *"Not in a literal, not as a constant, not as a variable name. Nothing."*

Answer (score 2):

### [Zsh + POSIX utilities](https://www.zsh.org/), 22 bytes

```
f()(tr 01 x-z<<<1;f);f
```

Thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger) for the shorter way to print `y`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@K/xP01DU6OkSMHAUKFCt8rGxsbQOk3TOu2/Zk1GamLKfwA)

### [Pure zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 24 bytes

```sh
f()(<<<$SPROMPT[29];f);f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@K/xP01DU8PGxkYlOCDI3zcgJNrIMtY6TdM67b9mTUZqYsp/AA)

#### Bonus: mandatory phrase from stdin — 21 - 10 bytes

```sh
read a;f()(<<<$a;f);f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@anJGvUJypUKOg8b8oNTFFIdE6TUNTw8bGRgXI0rRO@69ZkwEU/w8A)

Comment: Shorter way to print `y`: `tr 01 x-z<<<1`

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 14 bytes

```sh
x=Y;<<<$x:l;$0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxv8I20trGxkalwirHWsXgvyZXWk1GamLKfwA)

Set `x=Y`, then print `$x`, `:l`owercased. `$0` recurses.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 25 bytes

```python
while 1:print(chr(97|25))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0QjOaNIw9K8xshUU/P/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

**Apparently this isn't totally portable. My** `sys.version` **is** `2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 04:42:00) \n[GCC 4.9.2]`**, so if yours is different this might not work I guess.**

## Python 2 - (76-10)=66

```py
import sys
s=sys.stdin;a=`help`[1]if s.isatty()else s.read()
while 1:print a
```

Pretty long, but I wanted to go for the bonus (even though it cost more than 10 bytes). Checking if stdin is empty or not without prompting for input is long, apparently.

At first, I misread the bonus as taking an argument instead of stdin. I'm proud of my solution for that, so I'm posting it anyway ;)

## Python 2 - (52-10+∞)=∞ (invalid!)

```py
import sys
while 1:print(sys.argv+[0])[1]or`help`[1]
```

`sys.argv` is a list where the zeroth element is the filename and every element afterwords is an argument given to the program. I add a falsey value to the end of the list; if there are no arguments, the first element is that falsey value, otherwise it's the first argument. `a or b` in Python returns the first value that confirms what the outcome will be: If `a` is truthy, we already know that the whole thing will be true, so it just gets returned. If it's false, `b` is returned (since `False or b` == `b`).

Comment: @fry I could, but it would prompt the user. I wanted it to start spitting out `y\n` immediately if stdin was empty.

Comment: @fry That's weird, it works for me. It might be dependant on cPython? I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: good idea, on it

Comment: `r=raw_input();p=r if r else\`help\`[1]\nwhile 1:print p`

52 characters

Comment: Hmm, already the first line seems to have an `y` in it, the second one too.

Answer (score 1):

## Plan 9 rc: 20-10=10 (but not quite there)

```
f=`{cat};while()echo $f
```

The problem with this almost-solution is that it *must* have something on stdin.  I haven't yet been able to find a way to get it to print `y` if stdin isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Batch: 24 bytes

A yes.bat file with this content will work on most Windows XP and later systems with default settings:

```
@echo %COMSPEC:~12,1%&%0
```

Else this slightly larger yes.bat file (34 bytes) will work in all cases:

```
@set "T=%~n0"
@echo %T:~0,1%
@%0
```

Can be made down to 13 bytes if the file is called y.bat instead of yes.bat, but I feel that's cheating:

```
@echo %~n0&%0
```

Answer (score 1):

## linux (Ba)sh, 13 to 26 (23 to 36 chars) (repeats 'y' or the input, like yes)

create an executable (+x) file, named as you like (ex: `my_yes`), containing one of those possible contents:

```
echo ${*:-y};exec $0 $*  #23 chars, score 13, but loses spaces, and will choke on many inputs
```

*or*

```
echo "${@:-y}";exec $0 "$@"  #27 chars, score 17, but will choke on some inputs
```

*or*

```
printf "%s\n" "${@:-y}";exec $0 "$@"  #36 chars, score 26, a tiny more robust, but "longer"
```

and then execute it with the arguments you want, it will repeat them ad-lib. (With no arguments, it repeats "y", as the yes command does too)

```
$ chmod +x my_yes
$ ./my_yes
y
y
y
[ctrl-C]

$ ./my_yes '  It looks ok!'
  It looks ok!
  It looks ok!
  It looks ok!
  It looks ok!
[ctrl-C]
```

Comment: some inputs that can make it choke on the first 2 : first argument starting with a "-", for example. (and many others)

Comment: I use "exec" to ensure I don't bring the computer down very quickly with recursive bash (which 'yes' doesn't do, usually ^^)

Answer (score 1):

## C89, <s>31</s> 37 chars

```
main(){for(;;)printf("%c\n",'z'-1);}
```

Built on the idea of @LordAro, without filename requirements.

Answer (score 1):

## CFML, 247 bytes

This is more a "just for the heck of it" answer, as it's obviously hideously long (CFML earns no points for terseness); and I just realized it can't actually be *killed* without restarting the service, although it will indeed stop printing to the browser on an ESC character.

```
<html><body><cfflush><cfif isDefined("URL.i")><cfscript>a=URL.i;if(a is ""){a=chr(asc("x")+1);}while(1){writeOutput("#a#<br>");getPageContext().getOut().flush();}</cfscript><cfelse><form action="a.cfm"><input name="i"/></form></cfif></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 35 bytes

```
main(a,b){b='x'+1;for(;;)puts(&b);}
```

I don't know if this will compile correctly with all compilers on all platforms or not; if it doesn't work for you, let me know. I used several things here that I have never thought of using before. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Node.js, 53 chars (63 if you count `node -e ""`)

**update**:

- Reduced another 5 chars.
- Silly extra char removed.
- Reduced 2 chars, from  61 to 59.

---

The real `yes` does not uses stdin, but an argument, like:

```
yes n
```

Well, this answer works like that, it will print `y\n` over and over:

```
node -e "for(;;)console.log(process.argv[1]||34 .toString(36))"
```

And if you append an `n` after the line, it will print `n\n` instead:

```
node -e "for(;;)console.log(process.argv[1]||34 .toString(36))" n
```

No bonus, since I'm not using stdin.

Answer (score 1):

### [CAPL](https://github.com/C-Bouthoorn/CAPL)1.5+ ; 6 without input; 10 - 10 = 0 with input

**Sidenote**
I have read somewhere [link?] that custom languages aren't allowed in golfing questions, as they could make built-in functions that do exactly what the question is asking, however I made CAPL to make golfing easier *in general*. If you think this is not allowed here, let me know!

I got some ideas from [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) and [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) (You can move between lines and use hexadecimal characters to push numbers), some from Ruby and some from my own to make golfing easier.
CAPL reads from left to right, and goes one line down at the end of the line. If it is as the last line, the program will quit.

As no-one knows this language yet, I'll try to explain as much as possible.

**Outputting y. 6 bytes**

`bb*.n<`

`bb*` `b` is hexadecimal for `11`, so `bb*` is `11*11`=`121`, which is the UTF-8 equivalent of `y`. This value is pushed to the stack.
`.` Pops the top value from the stack, and outputs as UTF-8. As `121` is on top of the stack, the index is ignored here.
`n` Outputs a newline
`<` Sends the pointer back to the beginning of the line, thus repeating that line. As we don't expect input, we can do this safely without re-asking for the input.

**Outputting from input. 10 bytes, 0 after bonus**

`i~a&{X:.)}`

`i` Takes input from the user, pushes as UTF-8 on the top of the stack, and pushes the length after that. I.e. `[72,101,108,108,111,5]`
`~` Pops a number from the stack, then reverses that amount of bytes. I.e. `[111,108,108,101,72]`
`a` Hexadecimal for `10`, the newline character
`&{...}` Makes an infinite loop. We have input, so we can't send the pointer back to the line. I could place the function on the line below, which would safe me a byte, but newlines aren't allowed in this challenge.
`X` Removes the top value from the stack (The index from the loop)
`:.` Duplicates the top value, then outputs as UTF-8
`)` Turns stack right. (`[1,2,3,4,5]` -> `[5,1,2,3,4]`)

Howver, this means we start with a newline, then start outputting the input, then a newline, then the input, etc. If we're not allowed to start with a newline, use the following code with 12 bytes, or 2 after subtracting the bonus.

`iXa#~&{X:.)}`

The only new command here is `#`, which pushes the amount of items on the stack to the stack.
I removed the length from `i`, because adding 1, then swapping with the newline is longer than removing and getting the length again.

**Just for fun, here is a "Hello World" program**

```
"Hello World"#~
#?!;.<
```

The `?!` operation is the same as ><>'s

Comment: Actually the restriction applies to custom languages/libraries/features published _after_ the question was posted.

Comment: @manatwork That would mean my answer is invalid. Thanks for the clarification. I made this language, and wanted to do some golfing challenges to test what I could improve for future versions, if that makes anything better.

Comment: In my opinion this is not invalid, just not eligible to win. The restriction's goal was to prevent cheating, but as you included the statement about the language's freshness, this could hardly be considered a cheating attempt.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 19 bytes - 10 = 9

```
INPUT C$@L?C$GOTO@L
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QC](http://github.com/0xqookie/qc) 26 (26 - 10 = 16) bytes

`(00600F014"0178)0101A01$14`

The program requires an input on stdin because QC doesn't have a way to get arguments. Empty input just prints y.

#### Explanation

```
(00 read string into memory at address 00, address 00 is length, next bytes are the string itself
600F014 jump if values at 00 and F0, if not equal jump to address 14
"0178 Write 78(lowercase x) to address 01
)0101 increment value at address 01 by 01 which gives y
A01 print string and newline from address 01 until 00 is reached
$14 jump to address 14(print the next line)
```

Comment: Wait, It's decremented by 10, so it becomes 16 bytes, making this the ultimate answer!

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy, 15 - 10 = 5 bytes

Because Vitsy waits for STDIN to be entered, I have made the bonus input come in as command line arguments.

```
zl)[bD*][:ZaOu]
```

Explanation:

```
z               Grab the entirety of the input stack and patch it on the current.
 l)[   ]        If the stack has no members...
    bD*         Push 11^2 to the stack (this is the ASCII value for 'y').
        [     ] Loop infinitely.
         :      Duplicate the current stack.
          Z     Push the entire contents of the stack to output, top first.
           aO   Push out a newline to the out.
             u  Flatten the top two stacks.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C(GCC) - 161 bytes

```
main(int argc,char**argv){if(argc>1){while(1){for(int i=0;i<argc-1;i++){printf("%s ",argv[i+1]);}puts("");}}else{char*c=malloc(1);c[0]='x'+1;while(1){puts(c);}}}
```

Uses malloc to allocate 1 byte and set its value `'x' + 1`
If any input is provided as an argument(mulitple words work too) it will print it instead of y.

Ungolfed version:

```
main (int argc, char**argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        while (1) {
            for (int i=0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
                printf("%s ",argv[i+1]);
            }
            puts("");
        }
    } else {
        char* c = malloc(1);
        c[0] = 'x' + 1;
        while(1) {
            puts(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 17 - 10 = 7 bytes

```
IDö?.x1+;Ω
D,∞
```

Explanation:

```
IDö?.x1+;Ω  ■Main link
I           ■Input
 Dö?    ;   ■If(!input){
    .x1+    ■  Push 'x' and increment
            ■}
         Ω  ■Call link below

D,∞         ■Helper link
  ∞         ■while (true){
D,          ■  duplicate and print
            ■}
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 51 bytes

```
while(T){cat(paste0(letters[25],'\\',letters[14]))}
```

Literally outputs "an infinite stream of "y\n"'s", rather than "y[newline]".

In RStudio the output is truncated but it is otherwise infinite.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 27-10 = 17 bytes

```
x=scan(,'');repeat print(x)
```

Repeats `stdin` over and over and over. No `y` or `\n` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 6 bytes

```
b:*oao
```

By not including a `;` at the end, the **><>** will keep on swimming until he's released by a SIGINT.

#### Explanation

```
b:*oao
b         Push 11
 :        Duplicate
  *       Multiply top elements to get 121
   o      Print as character
    a     Push 10
     o    Print as character (yielding '\n')
          No program terminator, so our ><> will 
          keep on swimming this path forever.
^----'
```

## ><>, 17 - 10 = 7 bytes

The previous is quite a boring solution, so here's one that takes input from stdin. This abuses the fact that the default way of supplying input to a **><>** program is `echo 'input' | fish.py yes.fish`, where `echo` provides the `\n` character.

```
 i:0)?!v
0r}o:r~<
```

#### Explanation

```
 i:0)?!v     Load STDIN into the stack (reversed)

             NOP           <----------,
 i           Push a byte from STDIN   |
  :          Duplicate top element    |
   0         Push 0                   |
    )?       If (i > 0):              |
      !        Wrap around  ----------'
             Else:
       v       Move to the second part

0r}o:r~<     Print STDIN until halted

       <     Go right         <---------------,
      ~      Remove top element (duplicated   |
                -1 from EOF)                  |
     r       Reverse stack                    |
    :        Duplicate top element            |
   o         Output as character              |
  }          Rotate stack to right (go to     |
                next character)               |
 r           Reverse the stack                |
0            Push 0                           |
             Wrap around       ---------------'
```

The `0r` at the end allow sfor the loop to happen by wrapping
around, where we still assume the stack to be reversed with a `-1` on top.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 - (10-10) = 0 bytes

```
print;redo
```

Requires the `-ne` flags. Takes in a character(s) from STDIN, repeats the character(s) infinitely.

#### Example execution

```
perl -ne 'print;redo'
```

#### Explanation

This takes advantage of the `-n` flag in `Perl`, where it explicitly wraps `while (<>) { ... }` around the source code. The use of `redo` without an explicit label is also used. According to the documentation:
`If the LABEL is omitted, the command refers to the innermost enclosing loop.`

Answer (score 1):

### Mumps (M), 12 bytes - 10 = 2 bytes

Quite simple in Mumps (M), as the language allows single character commands and a newline is denoted by '!'...

```
R I F  W I,!
```

Breakdown:

**R**ead STDIN into **I**,
**F**or (with two spaces) = infinite loop,
**W**rite contents of **I**, then newline (**!**)

Works on both InterSystems & YottaDB (GT.M).

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 - 10 = -9 bytes

The wonderful thing about Husk's laziness is that computations involving infinite lists can be managed and used to produce useful output, like in this case :)

```
∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HHvP///yt5pObk5OsohOcX5aQoKgEA)

### Explanation

```
   Implicit argument
∞  Build an infinite list repeating forever
   Implicit join by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org) (raku -n) 9-10 = -1 bytes

```
.say;redo
```

Idea for redo from @booshlinux (I would have done: loop{.say})

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), -8 bytes

```
[,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Wuf/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUA)

```
[,  # full program
[   # forever...
 ,  # output...
    # implicit input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA), -3 bytes (7-10)

```python
l,[:mo]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt5c9u2Ev9fnwKx21qqJVvO0SR@lls7SV/dNnHGdqd943FZiIQkpiTBkKBlTY@vnrcLHiJ4iGB8eiaRRAC7vz2wWABLfyFm3Hvywg8@2a7PA0HCRdgnLhWzziTgLhG2y0ja5DDmx48D6lnwkTTgL/g3ZZ3kgQioycbU/LPTMR0ahuQwoKFJX@H33Q6Bv7W1tVMBHfokYFM7FCwICVAhlzSw6dhhIXSQHS02IYZhe7YwjG7InElvtyMb8G9d0pADMzJZI3beCmWHETm/UJ9TeDZUH42VR0seBwEjcwYMqGV7U8IuWQBaw680JOaMgqzI99si4wC6GC63GND9njohy@F@b/vMGtgesaig2WN7QjwuTQDDgdmWHVIhFt3ebtYlRx86GDgcyC9HIMpu73x3d7BzoQya8IAYfWIQYMq8yGUBFaxbIFVgVMEM7RVGjkCmass5suyXnhZxqJbZor7PPKvLA6sbE@71su4MdNYkOXjJUqs/UHSixDhjxjzigxEEs8iCiYJ9qIOqWhhpj7KNzmZ2SOa245BQcPABCt/EjJExGPxPJojPQ1vY3Ct43HxmO8xwOPdDIPrXPwpFRkx0CHRYJOVzZB6oBLCHkbSUvdSMHSqVe/19FM4I2HMMnQWXVKVms8njQwcj7iDN3cfeOUOXjYHteeqX1IkY4ZOlsyOnCi7YnvDAryuZoMVlp169IGMuBEQZ4LxSLCPu1ySd7YUsEN1h3KVZQC0EOELlXy/5EkBZeO4TGVgLLLifxrxijMjIqjMkYCIKvJzTlCdR0iUHDNnE066AplEF3M8Lfwcwh6nGTmEGIqA07meYQiaM9GFikvSnii99SkYwnehaRaShaZRbKijGWhw9rho9Lo/O@Vwe@0aYuGDlBMY4dVMSKVMwlrFXLfewrbhl0uNetVKGiQlPcCkNWaXIsqXoVDk@aY9eRkt6C5JymDcVs2qHjduKdBNXg8bukkVuakYOrJWSmgzuBIM7cUAfpFsM@b2M1TiyHSt@WOQnmOurOQk@MSBlUNIFtRHWNId9jLhginVwXU9XIgg@3HVxcSkv8rhuFJZ3MGuJ9D4ZlnOAUq/BiOwovaSPlHGO6qkVZC0CSwVBdztfixdMZVwysJp86oapYnplsHkGF60YgHcEmP9IRmpkqEsEzuWYCxiUImoekvbEUXL4ahk21ho1fRZErNm2I/J4Nac/Wpsj360EQpc@Dmwmn3hTp4P7h9MFhCyX0GAKU8ETsPXw5X4HUzjYjmz5CzIhexPQuUddtl9uNckezpv9TueMw4TCjQnM7XE07ZMIAtfE2jZxrgEXamHAmWybW9g1dPicWHzuER4JPxJJ93DbDCWwjo2bGmRqGFJmw3ApJLVGYsQYAZgit29K3CwBl6WBa5@c/vmuyy8@JduqOGqRQww/cTzEaOVSPz88H5zSQEfeAgTZW/6OQ12OXZaT7slImWvJh7ZgoRops2ye1HkF2YtiCEj6KBupWjcrPVgncpndgyi4r6arKyLNsGIS5bSWT6WH5Vlf8uQdfXI7GuQe65N7rEHuiT65JxrknuqTe6pB7pk@uWca5L7RJ/eNBrnn@uSea5B7oU/uhQa5l/rkXmqQc1q4sc60@LkFPR3PYy3mhY5x37SYGDoTzWoxM3TM@7qFL@vMjVkLd9Hx5h/a@IuOw/zUiqAOxb/Wdsn6a2YGDBMDXeLpI8z5BjoR@x9kc@Rdg82mDpsA2cjl7kSewlbxocsVuDpnlWB0OuGOw8Ydhjzy7Y77hALKagvVSGj3OuUFWwoQr/aQKM1o0Cj4xh8bKx1DPYOtTH@18uiiFPKcqyGd2dy56K0ipGRUm7ifKmvkLcV9rI@7OJ472K7Fvol@cGBZt@wAVS67STX8dID4TqMxXg@IewA50AH5NYJ8GznC9p3FPYD8WgfkdhxYBJuC91j2pR1W7SlvH@z2tg7aL6VKuRU5/B4wfqkD8XeE@ObK515doL5lq2uZPZQT6GNwHYRl5njbtzWBjV/yNQQGXdrrVQXpQ1vMbdjLtohK/yLod8dnN4r5Xx11fSXj4bvX92DPr3Tw/Y34jk/uAd7fOvAMhPfbveD7HfBVeN9p5Sa@BJwicF@esvPlyfXBylQhf2sABDTUM67kcqjPZazD5UBySS9k9IRRbwz0pDms5nPYgo@WPH3kk5ze1xzKKBzSY/5GwrtI2Ip8xzblaT2IwicrOHxu5KHX6VlC/R8V9fKyTRd4ev@miyrtT29gQEkaF6Vx@aWqfpwfMZFKlvHV12cZI8UmSWjge5vhKyha3rwlB5/N@NrqXBuf36A/4smCnLDaL1weeUJ3B@ctd3DDfjx0xR5O20Y3Y6f3DXZ6QHpY7QvX9IdvZbCMa62S0ojhYOfxc12/ywqzurDPLJ4r9DQAPMrWuOWtamPQrjjLSO5ddVh@gSzDOfWlocWcE1swNyTcu3Ywv/WIP9aQ70TalIt0kRKzgLG7ldG8dUWY11FZ5X1OSY@nqEeTe7huepkywV1iwuHd@wnOsVCgSJv4QbVm2LQoRr0DJGUDyGZjY@sDtz3JzustA1l28IUFDPVBz8QwB8EkF/pyV3rJ6OYTvTbKQfAa6rATdUDaJwgQsW0M@Uns6w6qzscVofpJiFYKIBS56sUCKPHg/RF5@iIpR8XfeyPy7Hn9OOXEEVicSyR4by@HA@hmuY/yci@r4GINdDfvTO6hKvbLz5YaIHeaxb6S6a8NRAKrOWVf6Xcl2r/laesk1jqLeolLhFx@8QanlSQ93TREluzEs7ndSToEA0snzvyS4JzW4szHlKs4plyVYkqnyQ3UuqabFrPiTOBo@1jD0bg8apHFGFi2fXD66ugoqXFs8rplKUKpZri2HKEgSrnYuPIyAv9kl645U6@Ben2Y1tZoY0PD0se1oupMgvuXNpt8bYT2VKGTCPpwDZw3bgsx39WL@VCNW2HYpcAV8/kV90TAHfK9w@fNCtlDhfzMwhDyaHrbNyCovj3aKnDtVFNiOqpuW260j7r4L5hHFrDfjTr2H646RvJK52MEbn0HihiNHqwmNv63AZo4ZGLOmPcQtpaoL8wuTfzv4TrQd@hAZyxwbdyYdW4mKOKrWuzKFjq55ToCgHhoyUJg6pAPkes3BHapddTrsFEf5RKERkQfENGPgAKzuTkk1mGbGge1fqaZ248ZN3yXsB27gcpuU4PdObL7FcteB7Jmtlx1XVZ3nPM@wqR35QZL2SkNdi4aLFQnVSZUvlK8sZi2UtqLgrSwJN@WrPu3KuqgUDqzfhS/@SFb/YDJg44we38T3xFMyozKdejVNcfVpefrZ/jSiC0g5ZqQ@Yx5sHXmwDiQ3ips0BWwncCu2GqoO25Xx6S@HJKhOUbW8m5entfaoqMfJEvFTQm4QgXA@lt5NZG@xVh8e1ErtLArk/mC/MQWYw4TGmtYgiDyReGNonKUTAa@kR8QDtGQBXHWT7nL4rc/58wTZB5wb9rHE1Y@B@MQ4MRVuHGKuvbm5OT4ZJdUDS/cacYDsvebtyAMulQYAK54uJ0TIa6vP3Lxlg/9RebvnbYJee2V6Gee6NFR7UK93JbRmt3JpwUL@yS0g0f/Bw)

### Explanation

```python
<implicit input>
l           - Push 10 (\n)
 ,          - Reverse stack
  [   ]     - While non-zero:
   :mo      - Duplicate, move the duplicate to bottom, output top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 60-10=50 bytes

```
+>>,[[>,]>+<]++++++++++>-[<[<+<++++++++++++>>-]]<[[<]>[.>]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcHBCYAwFAPQgdJ2gpBFQg4qCCJ4KDj/9yZ9b5/b9ZzvcVdBarZaBAY/ddMEsZB6QpuRh8JUfQ)

Explanation:

```
+>> add one (120 to be adden on later yeilding 'y')
,[[>,]>+<]  if there is input, read it and set a flag to skip the next loop
++++++++++>-  '\n' 
[
  <[<+<++++++++++++>>-] add 10*120 to first cell, shift \n back one cell
]
<[[<]>[.>]<] print the input or 'y\n'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <del>86</del> 80 bytes

with strict adherence to the `you are not allowed to use "y" or "\n" or their ASCII values (121, 0x79, 0171, 10, 0xA or 012)` rule

```javascript
for(;;)console.log(eval('T\\u'+(+[])+(+[])+(38+38+3)+'peError').toString()[6+4])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcRBCoAgEADA57jLUpciAs@9oG7VQcykEDc28/tGh2CY02RzWzmuVEXeXCk7C2iNluPNwdWBPbhsAqhpWR5FQPOK/01PHyR1uUGERWGdeExyRA84d9SuWMoL)

-6 bytes thanks to me

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), -8 bytes <sup>(2-10 bytes)</sup>

Not the most original method, but it's short.

```
{,
```

### Explanation

```
{         - While non-zero
 ,        - Print implicit input
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B%2C&inputs=aeugh&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <sup><strike>32</strike></sup> 31 bytes

```
for(;;)console.log((""+1/0)[7])
```

### Edits

- **-1 byte**: `while(1)` => `for(;;)`

### Explanation

- `for(;;)` is an infinite loop)
- `1/0`: A division by zero returns `Infinity` in javascript
- `""+` converts `Infinity` into a string
- `[7]` access the 8th character of `"Infinity"` (`y`)

To terminate the process do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (`SIGINT`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>92</s> 102 bytes

```go
package main;import(."os";."fmt");func main(){s:=string('x'+1);if len(Args)>1{s=Args[1]};{Println(s)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjfTChKTsxPTUxVyEzPzrDNzC_KLSjT0lPKLlaz1lNJyS5Q0rdNK85LB0hqa1cVWtsUlRZl56RrqFerahprWmWkKOal5Go5F6cWadobVxbYgVrRhbK11dQBQXUlOnkaxZm0txDaopcujlRKTkpVioVwA)

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>172</s> 182 - 10 = <s>162</s> 172 bytes

```go
package main;import(."os";."fmt";"io");func main(){s:=string('x'+1);if len(Args)>1{s=Args[1]}else if f,_:=Stdin.Stat();f.Size()>0{b,_:=io.ReadAll(Stdin);s=string(b)};for{Println(s)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU_LCsIwEPyVkIsJarA3MVTwD8QeS5GoSV1ME-muIJZ-iRcRvHr0X_wb6wv2sDszzM6cr2W8XG4HcsPx87E3650pLasMBA3VPtYkFI_IteKuIq45RC61O4T1RyNkg5MUqYZQit6x10-kBse8DWJWlyinSYPpe8uTorUeLetYN1hO0ow2EFRGhkTnpzI4WSGno2b1JiGqhTWbmffio5Ma_09WstUu1s28u8gHgbJtv-l_Ja55cactIOvGMA_BfvEX)

+10 bytes for removing "y" and newlines.

Comment: this has an "y" in it, as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 - 10 \$ \approx \$ -0.95 bytes

```
[z011D*C~ZK
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharo6sMDA1dtJzrorwhIlAJmAIA)

If calculating "11 squared" is cheating, here's one which doesn't have any numeric literals:

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 12 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.88 - 10 \$ \approx \$ -0.12 bytes

```
[z0AzZHAK~ZK
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZroqsMHKuiPBy966K8IUJQGZgKAA)

##### Explanations

```python
[z011D*C~ZK  # Implicit input (if given)
[            # while True:
 z0          #  Push the first input if it
             #  was given, or [] if it wasn't
   11        #  Push 11
     D*      #  Square to get 121
       C     #  Get chr(121) ("y")
        ~    #  Do a logical OR, yielding the input
             #  if it was given, and "y" if it wasn't
         ZK  #  Print with a trailing newline
```

```python
[z0AzZHAK~ZK  # Implicit input (if given)
[             # while True:
 z0           #  Push the first input if it
              #  was given, or [] if it wasn't
   Az         #  Push the lowercase alphabet
     ZH       #  Remove the last element, to get
              #  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"
       AK     #  Get the last element, i.e. "y"
         ~    #  Do a logical OR, yielding the input
              #  if it was given, and "y" if it wasn't
          ZK  #  Print with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>15</s> 10-10=0 bytes

```
{.puts.}do
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v1qvoLSkWK82Jf///0QA)

For some reason I thought the *only* way to get input from STDIN was `"#{STDIN.read}`, but I then realized that STDIN is already left on the stack by default.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 - 10 \$\approx\$ -8.354 bytes

```
(,
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIoLCIsInkiXQ==)

Prints the input forever. Simple.

Comment: Should this be -8 bytes?

Comment: oops :P thanks ineedmorechars

Comment: What??? a negative amount of bytes???

Comment: oh challenge specs

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 25 Bytes

```python
while 1:print(chr(~-122))
```

Never knew you could do bitwise operations on non-binary numbers!

Comment: ...what's a non-binary number? Like a float(?), but you're not even using a float

Answer (score 1):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle) `-f`, 9 bytes

Doesn't contain a *line* feed (`\n`) but it does contain a *form* feed (`\f`).

```
"x")oo:,
```

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#%22x%22)%0Coo%3A%2C)! The `-f` flag has no meaning in the online version, but in the command line it means that closing stdout will terminate the program (e.g. `trilangle -f yes.trg | head -n 10`).

Since the form feed doesn't render, here's a hexdump (reversible with `xxd -r`):

```
00000000: 2278 2229 0c6f 6f3a 2c                   "x").oo:,
```

Notepad renders the form feed character as an up arrow, so I'll be using the symbol `↑` in place of the form feed for the explanation.

The code unfolds to this:

```
   "
  x "
 ) ↑ o
o : , .
```

For lack of redirections, this simply executes in order:

- `"x`: Push the value of x (120) to the stack.
- `)`: Increment the top of the stack
- `o`: Output the character corresponding to the top of the stack ('y')
- `"↑`: Push the value of ↑ (12) to the stack.
- `:`: Divide the two values, so the stack now contains a single number (10). Line feeds are ignored by the interpreter anyways, so doing arithmetic is the only way to get a 10 on the stack.
- `o`: Output the character corresponding to the top of the stack ('\n')
- `,`: Pop the value from the stack, keeping memory bounded since it loops forever
- `.`: No-op

For lack of an explicit exit instruction, this loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

## [JAGL](https://github.com/globby/Jagl/) V1.0 20 - 10 = 10 With Bonus, 14 Without

```
Tdn{78h[}Sf{p9[pDd}u
```

Coulda probably done better, but here is the explaination:

```
Td                               Get a line of text input, and duplicate on stack
  n                              Negate its truth value (for the if)
   {78h[}                        Push a block which will push the y character, if called
         Sf                      Swap top two values on stack and if no input, push y
           {p9[pDd}              Push block which prints the input (or y) and a newline
                   u             Do until loop. Output always evaluates to true
```

Can be killed by SIGINT

Without bonus:

```
'x  '{1+}/{pd}u
```

explaination:

```
'x  '                            Pushes the string '\tx'
      {1+}                       Adds 1 to each character in the string, making it 'y\n'
          {pd}u                  Infinitely prints and duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <del>157</del> 154 bytes

Despite the common misconception that you have to use `System.out` to print anything to the console in Java, this program outputs to the console using a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) to the file described by [`FileDescriptor.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#out). Accoding to the specification for `FileDescriptor.out`, it is *"A handle to the standard output stream. Usually, this file descriptor is not used directly, but rather via the output stream known as System.out"*.

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(;;)new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out).write(new byte[]{120+1,9+1});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pascal: 40 characters

```pascal
begin while 1=1do Writeln(Succ('x'))end.
```

Outputs “y”, stops on SIGINT.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lazy K](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lazy_K), 167 bytes

`````
`k````ssi``s`k``ss`k``siik``s`k`s``si`k```s``s`kski``s``s`ksk``s``s`ksk```s``s`kski``s``s`ksk``s``s`kski``s`kk``s`k`s``si`k``s``s`ksk```s``s`kski``s``s`ksk``s``s`kskik
`````

It is probably too long...

````
```ssi``s`k``ss`k``siik                                              fixed-point combinator
``s``s`ksk```s``s`kski``s``s`ksk``s``s`kski                          \n
```s``s`kski``s``s`ksk``s``s`ksk```s``s`kski``s``s`ksk``s``s`kski    y
````

Answer (score 0):

### C 42

```
main(){while(1){putchar(11*11);puts("");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my Befunge interpreter:

```
"z"1-.25*.
```

10 chars.
"z" means push the ascii value of the characted "z", 1 means push the number one, - means subtract, . means print the ascii value of it and * means multiply. For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge

Answer (score 0):

## [Microscript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript), 19-10=9

`If['w2s]1{CaI#!Zx}h`

Besides the initial input, takes an extra input after each iteration and halts when and if any of the additional inputs is non-empty (the specs for the question said to provide a way to make it halt).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 34 bytes - 10 = 24

```php
for(;;)echo$argc>1?$argv[1]:y,"
";
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>'` or `php -nr '<code>' '<string>'`.

Or 56 bytes for an exact port:

```
for(;;)echo$argc>1?join(" ",array_slice($argv,1)):y,"
";
```

<sup>(-2 bytes with extended ASCII; -1 for the not-so-complete version)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 - 10 = -3 bytes

```
ØyṪ³ȯṄß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARUA6v//w5h54bmqwrPIr@G5hMOf////aGk)

### Explanation

```
Øy             # The string "AEIOUYaeiouy"
  Ṫ            # Take the last element, namely "y"
    ³          # The cmdline argument (empty list if none supplied)
     ȯ         # Either the cmdline if supplied or "y"
      Ṅ        # Print with a newline
       ß       # Recurse
```

Thankfully Jelly programs can always be C-c-ed.

### Alternative Sans Y; 10 - 10 = 0 bytes

```
“¢³ƒ»Ṫ³ȯṄß
```

If the 'y' in the original answer is unacceptable, here's one without. This works on the same principle, the string `“¢³ƒ»` is the compressed version of "Jelly"

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 40 bytes - 10 = 30

```
i=input()
while 1:print(i or chr(11**2))
```

Stops with SIGINT (Ctrl+C)

Answer (score 0):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 23 bytes noncompeting

```
120
8

17

1

4

11
6
6
```

Increments 120, transforms it to a "y", and repeatedly print it and a newline.

Can be stopped with SIGINT / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Variant that receives something from stdin instead:

## OIL, 13-10 = 3 bytes

```
5

4

11
6
2
```

Answer (score 0):

## AHK, 38 bytes - 10 = 28

```
c=%1%
Loop,3
FileAppend,% c Chr(9+1),*
```

- I may have misunderstood, but I think the `9+1` is allowed. If not, I'll delete this.
- If `Loop` is used without brackets `{}`, it is assumed that only the next line is part of the loop.
- If `Loop` is used without a count, it will repeat until it encounters a `Break`.
- Per the [help file](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm), if an asterisk is passed as the filename into `FileAppend`, it outputs to `stdout`.
- `%1%` is the first passed argument.
- If I could use the input variable `%1%` directly, that would have been nice. It gets funny with the `Chr` function following it, though, and would have ended up being more bites.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 8 bytes

```
While not(getKey:Disp Str0:End
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 15+3 = 18 bytes

+3 for flag `-w`, which ignores stdin and generates an endless stream of null bytes for input instead.

```
dbae
*}++g
 `zf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/PyUpMZVLq1ZbO51LIaEq7f9/A0MjYxNTM3MLSwA)
Note about the TIO: instead of using the `-w` flag, it uses input. The behavior is the same, except that input is finite. One byte of output per byte of input.

#### Explanation

```
*}+
 `z
```

This is a 1-clock. On the first byte, the `+` is active, and on the second byte, the other three elements are active. The two states alternate endlessly.

```
d ae
* ++g
   f
```

This produces the output corresponding to 'y'. These letters each map to a bit: `_gfed__a` -> `0b01111001` -> `0x79` -> 'y'.

```
db
*}
 `z
```

This produces the output corresponding to '\n'. Similar to above, but we have these bits: `____d_b_` -> `0b00001010` -> `0x0a` -> '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 39 bytes

```
while 1 {puts [format %c [expr 11*11]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/PCMzJ1XBUKG6oLSkWCE6Lb8oN7FEQTVZITq1oqBIwdBQy9AwNrb2/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 5 bytes - 10 = -5

```
a{:o!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P7HaKl/x////usWVqcUA)

Takes input via the `-s` flag and repeats it forever until the program is interrupted.

Comment: To qualify for the bonus, I think this should print `y` if no input is given.

Comment: @Cowsquack [Nope, it's optional](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/yes-is-91-lines-long/162321?noredirect=1#comment100392_42428)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes -10 = -2

```
╜É'x)Äo∟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1DmHO9UrNA@35D/qmP//v3pJanGJ@n8A)

### Explanation

```
╜É         else without if (executes block of 3 chars if input is empty)
  'x)      increment "x" to get "y"
     Ä     start block of length 1
      o    print TOS without popping
       ∟   do while true without popping
```

Quite straightforward, but gets the job done.

Comment: [You don't need to print `y` if there's no input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/yes-is-91-lines-long#comment100392_42428)

Comment: _maxb_ bug report for MathGolf: string input which contains spaces are automatically transformed to lists (even if they are already inside lists). I noticed this, because it screwed up the length builtins `£` and `h`: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/j/3@lktTiEhBW4gIzFZDZqBw0HoQLAA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think I overcomplicated the implementation of implicit input, which causes these errors. I'll see if I can switch to a pure `ast.literal_eval` statement for the input, which should solve a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org/), 25 bytes

```python
while 1:print(chr(11*11))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP//5dnZOakKhhaFRRl5pVoJGcUaRgaahkaamr@/w8A)

Answer (score 0):

[Python 3](https://www.python.org/), 26-10=16 bytes

```
x=input()
while 1:print(x)
```

Seems too easy. Never posted here before so probably done something dumb. What did I miss?

**UPDATE**
I don't think this is cheating (35-10=25):

```
exec("x=input()\nwhile 1:print(x)")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I think this question doesn't allow newlines so you should use `;` instead.  The question is a little confusing IMO and I've been here a while.

Comment: Does it satisfy constraint about closing program?

Comment: @WheatWizard, python doesn't support semicolons.

Comment: Oh right. So I'm not even allowed newlines in my source. Got it! :laugh:

Comment: Best I can get with the bonus is 27, and I need the walrus to do that: `x,*_=iter(lambda:print(z),z:=input())`

Comment: Actually, that will probably segfault eventually. A set can be used to keep it going indefinitely I think `set(iter(lambda:print(z),z:=input()))`

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 23 - 10 = 13 bytes

```
{while(1>0)println(it)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsJADIXhfU/x6CpZCHZbaHsBd@IBBjrW4DTKNCpSevYx9q0efPDfH5ZEyzskfOPSgs6WRSfGocdFxdCV9XOTFKnpj/x0s6Qkxlu5vhRzECXGWsH3jyyW0SHHMJ5Eo9PQoq539j45c7UVvz8)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 - 10 = 20 bytes

```c
f(a){for(gets(&a);puts(&a););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1GzOi2/SCM9taRYQy1R07qgFMrQtK79n5lXopCbmJmnUZafmQJUqAESTEktS83JL0gtKtYBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), filename: 22 bytes + content: 4 bytes - bonus: 10 bytes = 16 bytes.

- Filename (escaped unprintables): `.w.i.c\001.+.a\013.+l.w.el.a`
- Content: `.v.p`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vr/U9u4Ev/df4UQIbET7NghbQFH9DgK185RuIHeu3uvoYyxFeLBsT22kxCS3L/eW0l2YichhV7budehsS3trj672l19day4@9kOeqHrUVmRpZgmSKV9s9@z4juk642GSe/DIErQ6dH14ekpOTKTUUjRLU3swO@gg7pDB3W/73mocVA2ymVeCwJ7lu8s16ayfjv88JbgkpzRqeFMIKtSSmP2qO1PxYs6xRmK38/e/Xl9@eENaej6Tlb42/nluz9P/3t9dH5xcXz0gRimbcUU4dL458PLt9f/Ob64fHd@tl8bTTFyfXmkcC0DFAaxe2@yj9rPpkljy54x/m8lH@31PSuhKO4yriBM4G0YRE4cem5iWp5rxUi9RZXS2Kjh0k94WiEV9qyYZ7@fnh69f0P2i@3IrHHHjLtuJ@FAHMTo0wJqdwNU2lR464bCP5MgQIHngOpugoxUGh1YHsIbqGN5McWTyRitop1Cq0mrpVaMOOk6UUXq9H07cQMfWTdgRrkX3yrjMHL9BGEaRUGEDIQRlHIBsq6Y0zkL9FcsRzTZtpWx25Hdm36nQyNCMFbGnSCyacfrx11ZMYGGyECd0GgCD8/1KUqpFRM4ob5FdAUe/chH8DBtL4hpygJt2iQlZ9T2xl8YYSVrDoNjgMrjuH8jY6RVS3gbY4Bk8oKPn9BVFfGiWYtTJ/A8K9KJbaZNgmFmWvWs0U2GfMyfcULDWo01Pfs8IPzVSjJr8U9zVk90czoXmTfGWEIozwKfeS4pZ183vvEs/062OVMK1SZkpzGZyHstYpfLdosYOwrj@vn4l3dnjI72wmREMH/gmXiC@QMvtYdQZg3MK7kfy2CuOLHsu228j5Vicew@0HlxBLErs5@YUocX9SzwVJ1jEk4mSZsoATgsbGJmC0Qtu4tiO3IheoKO@IyCfgJ@IW1uIk2KqOUEvjcC97XiHk8TVoJarcqH88PL9zmvhacVuonlyX7eSPLLFy3il8t@i@zpymvZr@00lH1/wbp2zymyteEVIdkHE@8oYGP28jJ7eZW@NLOq5gt4yXj2Zg0aegOeG2TvpXjs5qiAy9DzbIa@N@NrCD7D2Emfr4odCx1AI8tL@ymM6ED02VTK18rZCwvD1yV9Xy7pEMI4I@Ayhe5z45V0RSmXhUjiBAkTCO6eskC8fRJxxH9LmNsMOp8FWL5GxNm8IUY0F/NXXasrvCyLAOzNcTHqaRYbHYS37LaPtwsQzQUjCMUF6hIPneOzN0Xo8zZXtTiVuD9JCpaY3/2E3px/ePP@8Oji/O3xxXHBC4d3RS/849fKvGfcWz@I6LUD9KGVdEVY@TROWKyIoC6BYbGFU3SzOsh64zw8zWIDJ4QJpCAQibThNtLu4f9oG0HgaA8YTRBmMIyDcgObed5NFI/8xLpHInGHUXAbWb2UJs3/qZGz9lXVXA0fXGShkBhjznifCHX@qn/6OLwfPVyV6uOcRMiTrNoAbT2u7a1Iw7q6d1UD9@BZ5aPriDwCL1dXpGzOPoBdJBbBxhyq7SOUJhtWpGnMyRQzc5VSauwMFzQcQsPCJm0JI5ZxZJfMmlAN0z0AHV1VVcbgY4Ios@IMn3tl5iod6lE26K@qnc7eZm2AeLwEKyjCAjeQ44c5LuVAX4cHaFVDWQtqBclcazUHeBmb/zxsfo@sa5V5eK9VZMkUar4wC6V@r0qgS3Jl09x7EJPmbg34QOCWASkgV8f6FYCIyjqr9HsHulkoWoCwKA6GNZ5u5DZut/02VoDiMSgCfrH@G/aAW@yBvPXnfGDYdLTeIAAZK/mGZpH1cEVSqjknmyIxdj5nUxD057NYHyPO91w2j2DAzOWYYKG9pPX1cqiaZqHT5iqTJZVRTiM2gUwnsW2sXe/D1ACWBtROqIOOz0@AccFDs9lVKn3RVb5WMoIE7sNMpk8fc6S8RjCZKDYb3xLD/EZAbmAAu3sSihfLKNQfBqO528qcrlxOX1ovdr9omLVy8/hcP@wnyA8SeEvoLY0KEKf56HoMC3IGWbna3F0Iq@W23PjR5la7eN60S3o92UYM5KBq6DV5jvWZzrnQeG5sWzFwx7dVZ/DUULefN8QU0syTEiy0ui7Bxs9r/xum9sFTUruYpcC0pMWGp/ih3oClca1WtMmQPDI/yRUXjeUugV6qJfFwLfwOnq9ZeZqH8dKFtd4yJS0qml9J57ykfxMCf81YJSF6Xiex@iRccg@FxVHB7WchGrF05dAOLDUdvhYF0oWMtSiNTyf4OlepJqGy1lbDL45nq43yZVURGjpr4@BJLvuI06YAoIWVCWiFovffUFHSWND0/oZsyItqtAoFDejlr9B@FVHjcRORxpKN7m@eZqDR9zTQaJWBDv4dBho90UAP39NADzdkyT6E/DsM9PBEA1nFvLuCInletuxSKyQ/aEHZW4LGWt8gfFty9UAvz4FfEUb9NaO8w41W2Mcxl/dcxHaIvmrzw1gSWfuSlRe8b9E1aj/K5uo/BKp@aVG/yNBiK@iFssXV/DfUb@Mf6lf9UR1ReibQgUHW5ZNB47sA58AGRhXEF1Z0pX30QKNAddyBG7uBv256BEjJoHEwMF6zSdKgUR8Yyj5/NeqDxvq50tb/tZW2/oGVtuZW2lpjpfludpa7Nhb3i88CWNFFEY3DwHdc/xZpFp/Vfpd9Y75d/sevYrsc3VKfRuwklB34zI5vxA65Wun4Vo8WTxj5wRBYRAxEXA8@IvEhge/v5rZPpUyAJO0j/t5zHcejqFyW0iOCrZid0hqbm9X6FNSTAgeph8hHaoL6BlIHUJRESD2KkW40dpovXr7a3UOVj22/elWButuIhkiDF2t4x6hhXUOaL0EkP3PCaQUuyfNDia243fYFxfCOUQBmWEZUuKXqhUGnbrelCvzLDeDikMnEQF3hNkwV6wBK0Iof11amFWZbu0vtO@h4cAWbxrEVsTMIxM4jUMf1qMTWYERnkCnRpezAOjMFdIdc1T52Tq6qCl@uEQOJU@LHSOlxSkqXSBk/@6GCWJ8Nnhkdgxv4CfX5WR6Dh6w4O2PJSxECDHYcw7wElwxhwhX9htC6nkNo1ndpB8R1rVpfvUdRPFyoC35ZGHvmmtmadlwxGTYTZZ2hSJmWc0UyS6wwxCwmYJG7GBHMSMWASFfCTwyI/BaBqABensL4NoG0ehtA0LDdAmlxGsVjOkUlFYKq8a8Np3S8aIsvvGwTtqcitk14Up0TZsZJDZJRq8bVVXFTZZlvTsomn0v1q86GFoimiwUZz3wfaIEgSxbmLFsUHAlyRkVao730dIWlZR2lR9RKTw@XwEvCjwAUC4KO61ueN5JEdEiS8nmT@bVDIw2F97Rna/zSjRv3NEYdQESlNfeFmqRLR8iKKOpEQY/XF6p7geN2XPAXC91AQ2zU@/DunNXAXzdJwni/Xr91k27/RrODXv2Xt@qH0KIn1vCB@vWCOGkTWAolbAf36EjXJOnk7PD9MTv7TZ22og01V7Pbum5oNc1q68aOVvOgkHqaVYGOujz//eLomGgDLfycDyouCE@GNlJtPgoXQk5wPVrNmVcRyWm4pddRGFBxZUiWS3J2oerw4pfr94d/8gtYkwmvb@jNXUXdUxQFM3Zx04Zg1k9I9Y0Jj34I/kHSNyar4h5B2E9E0E9Y1KqUpeFPqFqHHCs@ULUEH1x@dkOE4fvIwPNbYX1WDH17VS5DYbRUOAfhNJF61iwQCFRODpU6mchhDCwBCsFhaeL26HZoh/3tQfxgOpCXlbxezcmj@SxTLLFcD8zRbHAVK4bbltSG0XzV3N152dyV2LDTlrX2eLc9bSuletuoVyZph1TGVo3dSpiyWZxIW5YJAwpG4tIbu20384q5Ayg47aCKmI01kBewUR@AUKeiZMDSRnrWvUf9r@10EZQEZ57NC0U8Eiy@AARENXyJeSOqiDsP5xeX7AbG6QnJDlAx5C/FPGf3nuqfuDOW6uxS2DkhhpLed@KS0ekJJ@OTXKDlagrSlXTikH9nkpu8iqzXhKxHzk5EvhOc5yeXqOTmSaei4vQkXyggY56ftvrsmkmpIS7IwRMgqa/FdQWhwcZ5Jl7YC1AZqdwOwu32VgD8mT7jVPYw6YDcfKNc/s6O8IclbcEzJnEXqfFnK75z3b8B)

### With comments

```
XX.z
# while size==0 || pop!=0; do
.a.wXX.z
  # push getchar; dup; push 1; push pop+pop;
  # NOTE EOF is -1
  .a.i.c\001.+XX.z
# done
.a.aXX.z
# push 11; push pop+pop;
.a\013.+XX.z
# push whatever not zero; while pop!=0; do call content; push whatever not zero; done
.al.w.el.a
```

```
XX.z
# get called, with my stack initialized to original one
# reverse; pop all to putchar for each of them
# implicitly return, pushing each content of
# my stack from bottom to pop to original one
.a.v.p
```

---

## Pxem, filename: 14 bytes + content: 0 bytes = 14 bytes.

- Filename: (unprintables are escaped) `.w\005\005.+\001x.+.p.a`
- Content: empty.

Wow, shorter than above!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vr/V9rIFv89f8U4IiRgIEFs1TB2XavbnrWyR923@16xnpgMkmNIcpIAIrD/evfOTAIJINVu27Ovp5Jk5t47n3vn3jtfbTPqfrb8XuC4VFZkKaIxUmnf6PfM6B5pWr1u0IfAD2N0dnxzdHZGjo14FFB0R2PL9zrosGbTQc3ruy6qHxb1YpHXgsCe6dnLtYms346u3hFckFM6NZgJZFVKYcwelYOpeFGnOEXx@/n7P28ur96SuqbtpIW/tS7f/3n235vj1sXFyfEV0Q3LjCjChfHPR5fvbv5zcnH5vnV@UBlNMXI8eaRwLX0U@JHzYLCPys@GQSPTmjH@byUf7fVdM6Yo6jIuP4jhbeiHdhS4TmyYrmNGSL1DpcJYr@DCT3haIiX2LBnnv5@dHX94Sw7y7ciscduIuk4n5kBsxOiTAmp1fVTYVHjrusI/Y99HvmuD6k6M9EQaHZguwhuoY7oRxZPJGK2inUKrcbOplvQo7tphSer0PSt2fA@Zt2BGuRfdKeMgdLwYYRqGfoh0hBGUcgGyphjTGQd0VySHNN62lLHTkZ3bfqdDQ0IwVsYdP7Rox@1HXVkxgIbIQB3TcAIP1/EoSqgVAzihvkk0BR790EPwMCzXj2jCAk1aJCFn1NbGXxhhJW0Og1@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@OX@bhz5vc1WLU4n7k6RgifndT@ht6@rth6Pji9a7k4uTnBcO7/Ne@MevpXnPOHeeH9IbG@gDM@6KsPJoFLNYIRxZAQyLTZygm9VBghtn4VVNNkRCmEC2AZGoOtxG1Qf4G20jCJzqI0YThBkM/bBYx0aWdxNFIy82H5BI0UHo34VmL6FJMn1i5LR9VTVWwwcXWSgk@pgzPsRCnb9qnz4OH0aP14XaOCMRUiKr1kFbl2t7JzKupu5fV8A9eFb56Ngij8DL9TUpGrMPYBeJRbAxh2p7CCXJhhVVq8zJFCN1lUJi7BQXNBxAw8ImbQkjlnFkh8yaUHXDOQQdHVVVxuBjgii14gyfc21kKm3qUja8r6qdzt5mbYB4vATLz8MCN5Cjxzku5VBbhwdoVV1ZC2oFyVxrNQN4GZv3Mmxej6xrlXl4r5lnSRVq7Bq5Uq9XJtAlmbJp5t2PSGOvAnwgcEuHFJCpY/0KQERljVV6vUPNyBUtQFgUB8MaTzdyG7fbXhsrQPEUFAE/X/8Ne8DJ90DW@nM@MGwyWm8QgIyVbEOzyHq8JgnVnJPNhhg7n54pCPrzRaxPEWd7Lp1HMGDGckyw0F7S@mY5VA0j12lzlcmSyiijEZsrJtPVNq7eHMDUABYB1IqpjU5ap8C44KHphCqRvugqXysZQQL3YCbTp085UlYjmEzkm43uiG58IyC3MIDdPwvF7jIK9YfBaOw1U6crFpOX5u7eFw2zVm4Wn@MF/Rh5fgxvMb2jYQ7iNBtdT2FB9iAtVxt7C2G13JYTPdncahfPmnZJr2fbiIEclHWtIs@xvtA5FxrPjG0rBu7ormwPnhvq1suGmFyaeVaChVbXJdjoZe1/w9Q@eE5qF7MUmJY02fAUPdbqsAquVPI2GZIn5ieZ4ryxnCXQS7UkGq6F38FjaTbJZGkexksH1nrLlDSvaHbRnPGS/m0A/BV9lYTwZZ3E6uNgyT0UFkc5t5@FaMjSlU07sNS0@VoUSBcy1qI0Pp3g61ylHAfKWlsNvzierTbKl1VFaGivjYNnuewTTpsAgBZWJqAVij58Q0VJfUHTh1uyIS@q0cwV1KGXv0L7VUT1p01E6ks2erh9noFG39NAo1UGOvx3GGj0TAM9fk8DPd6SJfsQ8u8w0OMzDWTm8@4Kivhl2bJLzYD8oAVlbwkaa32D8D3J1QO9PAd@TRj114zyNjdabh/HWN5zEdsh2qrND31JZOVLVl7wvkXXqPwom6v/EKj6pUX9IkOTraAXyhZX899Qv41/qF/5R3VE4YVABzpZl08G9e8CnAMb6GUQn1vRFQ7QIw191XYGTuT43rrpESAlg/rhQH/DJkmDem2gKwf8Va8N6uvnSlv/11ba@gdW2ppbaWuNlea72Wnu2ljcLz73YUUXhjQKfM92vDtUNfms9rvsG/Pt8j9@Fdvl6I56NGRnnuzAZ3Z8I3bI1VLHM3s0f5bID4bAImIg4nrwEYkPCXx/N7N9KqUCJOkA8feeY9suRcWilBwRbEXsPFbf3CzXpqCe5NtIPUIeUmPU15E6gKI4ROpxhDS9vtPYffV6bx@VPra98nUJ6u5CGqAqvJjDe0YN6xrSeAUi@ZkTTipwQZ4fSmxF7bYnKIb3jAIwwzKixC1Vyw06NastleBfZgAXh0wGBuoSt2GiWAdQglb8YLY0LTHbWl1q3UPHgytYNIrMkJ1BIHYegTqOSyW2BiMag0yJJqVH06kpoDvkcvVj5/S6rPDlGtGROA9@ipSeJKR0iZTxsx8qiLXZ4JnSMbi@F1OPn@UxeMiM0jOWrBQhQGfHMcxLcEEXJlzRbwit6zmEZn2XdEBUq5Zrq/co8ocLNcEvC2PPXDNd045LBsNmoLQzFCnVcq5IaokVhpjFBCxyFyOCGSkfEMlK@JkBkd0iEBXAy1MY3yaQVm8DCBq2WyAtTqN4TCeopFxQ1f@14ZSMF23xhZdtwvZUxLYJT6pzwtQ4iUFSalW/vs5vqizzzUnZ5HOpftXZ0ALRdLEg5ZnvAy0QpMnCmGWLnCNBzihJa7SXnq@wtKyj9IRayenhEnhJ@BGAYkHQcTzTdUeSiA5JUj5vMr@2aVhFwQPtWVV@vcaJelVG7UNEJTUPuZq4S0fIDCnqhH6P1@eqe77tdBzwFxPdQkNs1Lt632I18L8bx0F0UKvdOXG3f1u1/F7tl3fqVWDSU3P4SL1aTpy0CSy5EraDe3ysVSXp9Pzowwk7@02ctlQdtjVtl/1VK/CrP1Qr1aBqlqCPLlu/XxyfkM/ZWOL8eDK0kGrxwTcXaYLjyWrOvIpITqIsuXDC8Ik7QbJckNMbU0cXv9x8OPqT37CaTHh9XWvsKeq@oiiYsYu7NASz7kGqp0940EPMD@K@PlkV7giifSJifcKCVaUs@35C5RqkVvGBygX44PLTiyEM30cGnl/76rNi6NLrYhEKw6XCOQi7gdTzRo5AoLIzqNTJRA4iYPFRAH5KY6dHtwMr6G8PokfDhnSsZPVqTJ5MY6lisem4YI5GnatY0p22pNb1xuvG3s6rxp7ERpu2XG2P99rTtlKotfVaaZJ0SGlsVthlhCmbvIlsZRowjmAkbrWx63Qzr5g7gIKTDiqJSVgduT4b7AEItUtKCixppGc@uNT72k4XsUhw6tC8UIQhweILQEAww5eYLqKSuOrQurhkFy/OTkl6boohbSlGi91Uqn3izliosWtfLUJ0JbnUxCWjs1NOxue2QMvVFKQr6cTZ/s4kM2cVya4ByY6cn4o0Jzhbp5eo4GRJp6Li7DRbKCBjnpa2@ux2SaEubsDBEyCpb8QtBaHBRisVL@wFqPREbgfhdnvLB/5Un3Eiexh3QG62US5/Z0f4w5K24BmTqIvU6PPf)

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh, 29 bytes

```pascal
for ((;;))<<<${(#)$((11*11))}
```

[tio example](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPD2lpT08bGRqVaQ1lTRUPD0FDL0FBTs/b/fwA) (times out)

Not cheating like the bash answer...

Comment: [Shorter zsh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237194) (a recursive function saves 1 byte compared to `for ((;;))`, and I found a shorter way to construct `y` without `y`, there may well be even shorter ones)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nooklang](https://github.com/HoangTuan110/Nooklang), 14 bytes

```
{120 1 + c p}t
```

Right now this isn't available on any online coding platform yet, so you will have to run the code from your computer.

Explaination:

```
{
  120 1 + # Returns 121 (aka ASCII value of y)
  c # Converts the value to character
  p # Prints out the character
} t # Infinite loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 37 - 10 = 27 bytes

```
var x=readLine stdin;while 1>0:echo x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3VcsSixQqbItSE1N8MvNSFYpLUjLzrMszMnNSFQztDKxSkzPyFSogiqF6FiyshDAA)