# Create a Parrot Program

Tags: code-golf, string

Given an input, output that input followed by a newline endlessly.

Input will be a string consisting only of printable ASCII characters (`0x20-0x7E`) and newlines (`0x0A`).

If input is length 0, endlessly output newlines.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: Half of [yes is 91 lines long](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/yes-is-91-lines-long).

Comment: [So related it hurts.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42428/44713)

Comment: @VoteToClose I _knew_ I've answered this before..

Comment: **Microsoft, 1 Steve Ballmer** — *developers, developers, developers, developers, ...*

Answer (score 12):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 8 bytes

```bash
yes "$1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzK1WEFJxVDp////Hqk5OfkK4flFOSkA)

Comment: damn, 10 minutes late! but this does not print out newlines as newlines.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean the `yes`-newlines but any newlines that could be contained IN the input are instead printed out as `\n`.  kind of depends on how you read the question :D

Comment: @Blauhirn Oh I misunderstood this part :/. You need to call this as `./script $'Hello\n World'` to include real newlines. [On TIO you can just add a newline to the command line argument](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzK1WEFJxVDp////Hqk5OflcCuH5RTkpAA)

Comment: Are the quotations necessary? `yes $1` works fine for me

Comment: @DrnglVrgs this does not work for me for an empty input

Comment: @DrnglVrgs Unless the input contains spaces.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
[,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Wuf/fyUwAAA)

Comment: Why aren't you doing `[I,`?

Comment: @FrodCube: Because unfortunately that doesn't work with empty input :(

Comment: @FrodCube: Actually, the question states input of length 0 and not empty input so I can decrease this :)

Comment: 05AB1E is smart enough to implicitly push inputs. The language I'm using now (Ohm) only does it the first time... After it gets the first input it tries to push the input in the next line and crashes since there is not one

Comment: @FrodCube: Yeah, it's a pretty new feature in 05AB1E actually. I'm sure Ohm will get it eventually as well.

Comment: `[=` also works and is a smiley face; the smile is the only benefit lol.

Answer (score 7):

## [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), 20 Bytes

OP did not specify *how* the output should happen, said only it has to happen endlessly with a newline after it. AHK was not tailored for cmd interaction. So the output happens repeatedly in a `ToolTip` at mouse position:

[image: tooltip]

```
loop
tooltip,%1%`n`n
```

I like AHK's `loop` feature. `loop` repeats the next block forever, `loop, 10` would repeat it 10 times. Sometimes I miss this feature in other languages like Python.

The escape character in AutoHotkey is `` ` `` (so there are no problems with backslashes in Windows paths). For some reason, a trailing newline is ignored so it is needed twice. (`trayTip` might not have this "bug" but I cannot test it because running with wine)

### old answer:

```
loop
msgbox,%1%
```

I just realized that OP probably wont like this solution, the output happens with user-interaction and includes no newlines. I'll look for another way.

Comment: Well, you've got my upvote for a creative solution

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>f(a,console.log(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i5NI1EnOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jUVPzf5qGkkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqKSpvV/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
∞┼,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f//Uce8R1P26Pz/n5iUAgA)

It doesn't work with an empty input because Ohm is bad at input handling compared to other languages, but you can input "".

Explanation

```
∞     Infinite loop next code (until ";" or end of line)
 ┼    Get first input
  ,   Println
```

Comment: This looks cool... Could you explain it :D

Comment: @BetaDecay done!

Comment: FYI, Ohm v2 (hopefully coming soon-ish) will have much better input handling than before!

Comment: @NickClifford cool! I'm looking forward to that! I like your language

Comment: Oooo... Is Ohm like 05AB1E with different commands?! *Fervently starts reading GitHub pages*

Comment: @carusocomputing Ohm is like 05AB1E with different commands and Jelly-like links

Answer (score 5):

## sed, 5

```
:      # label (unnamed) 
p      # print the pattern space
b      # branch back to the label
```

Unnamed labels is an undocumented "feature" in sed that works with version 4.2.2, but may not work in future versions.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Ṅß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpbD8////@9clJpYkqqQqBCQWFSUX6IQUJSfXpSYqwgA)

Print with a newline, repeat the whole link (program).

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 27 bytes

```
+[>,]++++++++++[[<]>>[.>]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO9pOJ1YbDqKjbWLt7KL17GJtYv//dy5KTSxJVUhUCEgsKsovUQgoyk8vSsxVBAA)

Comment: Could you save a byte with `,[>,]++++++++++[[<]>[.>]<]`?

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 21 bytes

```python
def f(s):print s;f(s)
```

*Assumes no recursion limit*

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo1jTqqAoM69EodgaxPmfpqHkXFpSkpOqkJZZnKGopPkfAA)**

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 2 bytes

```
òÙ
```

You can't try this online for obvious reasons.

```
ò    'Recursively
 Ù   'Duplicate the current line downwards
```

Comment: TIO actually runs for 60 seconds then terminates and prints the STDOUT up until the termination point truncated to the first 128KiB.

Comment: In `V` because the output it inside of an nvim session, and isn't printed to STDOUT until it finishes, TIO kills the session and sees nothing on STDOUT.  I didn't know about what you said, but unfortunately it doesn't fix V

Comment: Ahhhh... That's unfortunate, I forgot the properties of V, I've only used it once unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 4):

## [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language), 33 bytes

**Code:**

```
x=input " repeat [ label x bk 9 ]
```

**Explanation:**

```
x = input "               ; Input Stored in x as String
repeat [                  ; Endless Loop
    label x               ; Print x in Current Position
    bk 9                  ; Move Back 9 pt
]
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 12 + 2 = 14 bytes

Run with the `-n` flag.

```
loop{$><<$_}
```

Edit: Thanks for @sethrin for the `-n` flag!

Comment: Use the `-n` flag and skip the `gets`.

Comment: @sethrin Nice one! I did not know about this flag!

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 6 bytes

```
AN/qvo
```

[Test it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICBBCk4gLyBxIHYKICBvCg==&input=dGVzdAoxIC4uIDIgLi4gMw==&speed=200)

```
  A
N / q v
  o
```

- `N/A` Push Newline(10) and input onto the stack
- `v` redirect into the loop
- `o/q` loop that outputs a character and pushes it to the bottom of the stack continuously

I was going to remove the EOI (-1) indicator from the stack, but it doesn't appear to affect the output any, so have left it saving bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
#
V[R!&@v1+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fmSssOkhRzaHMUDv2////Hqk5OfmKAA)

*-2 bytes thanks to totallyhuman*

### Explanation

```
#\nV[R!&@v1+]  Implicit input of string as charcodes
#\n            Push charcode of newline
   V           Create stack2
    [R...v1+]  While loop, runs endlessly
      !&@      Print entire stack1 as chars without popping
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
s=input()
while 1:print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69Eofj/f6W0/HwlAA)

Input is expected to be a Python literal (quotes for a string, square bracket or parentheses with comma-separated items for a list/tuple, etc.)

Python 3 would be +1 byte because `print` is a function, but also could do raw input without the 4-byte penalty for `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 14 bytes

```
cycle.(++"\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802uTI5J1VPQ1tbKSZPSfN/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkYKKQklidqqCkYEBkJmmoBSQn5NTqfQfAA)

Append a newline to the input and make list of infinite copies of it.

Alternative version, also 14 bytes:

```
unlines.repeat
```

Comment: The alternative version is quite elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
ẉ?↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuTvtHbRv@/1dyLkpNLElVSFQISCwqyi9RCCjKTy9KzFVUAgA)

Port of [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124664/48934).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 20 bytes

```
for(;;)echo"$argn
";
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 24 bytes

```
f(char*s){puts(s),f(s);}
```

Basically a recursive function that outputs the string before calling herself again.
Its my second post on codegolf so please be nice :p

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 21 bytes

```
putStr.cycle.(++"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 16 bytes

```
i:0(?v
:o71.>~a{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMO@jMsq39xQz64usfr/f0MjYxNTMwA)

As mentioned in the comments below my first attempt may have misunderstood the question so the newer 16 byte solution has been made, I have left the original below so people may see.

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 bytes

```
<ov!?+1:i
oa<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3ya/TNFe29Aqkys/0eb/f0MjYwA)

Comment: I think there's been a bracketing problem: this code returns "that input followed by (a newline endlessly)", while most of the other answers give "(that input followed by a newline) endlessly"…

Comment: @Notatree, Thanks for mentioning this, I have updated my answer to respect your comment :)

Comment: Nice, my best try was 17 bytes!

Comment: @Notatree, I changed the check in the first line from 1+?!v to 0)?v which saved a byte, what was your solution, would be nice to see more ><> answers :) - I also believe with some nifty mirrors you may be able to remove the jump instructions too but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: My solution was:
`<v?(0:i`
`v>~a`
`>{:o` (which isn't formatting properly). The jump is nice — I should start using those more often!

Comment: @Notatree, you were really close to the 16 bytes as well, change your second line to a\~ then move your last line around 1 to o>{: and you would have made it. the jump is just to cut  out on extra mirrors across lines but yours works just as well :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
OpU;ß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/378g1Prw/P//lTxSc3LydRTC84tyUhSVAA)

**Explanation**

```
OpU;     output the input with a newline
    ß    run the code again with the same input
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 40 bytes

```c#
s=>{for(;;)System.Console.WriteLine(s);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 4 bytes

```
`GDT
```

[**Try it Online**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HdJeT/f/WM1JycfIXy/KKcFHUA)

**Explanation**

```
`     % Do...while loop
  G   % Grab input
  D   % Display it on a new line
  T   % Literal TRUE to create an infinite loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 26 bytes

```
f(char*s){for(;;)puts(s);}
```

A function, `f`, that takes a C-style string as a parameter, `s`. The body of the function loops repeatedly, passing the string to the library function `puts`, which outputs the string to the standard output (stdout) along with a trailing new-line.

Pretty simple stuff. The only hack here is taking advantage of default-int for the return value and then not actually returning a value. That doesn't matter in this case, though, since the function never returns (it just keeps printing forever)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLM6Lb9Iw9pas6C0pFijWNO69n9mXolCbmJmngaIkaejAFaopZCsyVXNxQnUF20Yq2nNxVmUWlJalKdgYM1V@/@/R2pOTj6XQnh@UU6KIgA)

Comment: `f(char*s){puts(s);f(s);}` saves a few

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
q{_n}h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7A6Pq824///AMegIH/sIEQRAA)

Comment: @LuisMendo Ooh didn't read that part...

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
#
```

<s>Unfortunately I can't remove `Q` :(</s>

You need to run from command-line like this, so that this is competing:

```
python3 pyth.py -c "#
"
```

The interpreter has been fixed too.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 20 bytes

```
x={println it;x(it)}
```

Comment: Does this run forever since it is recursive?

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 34 bytes

```
s->{for(;;System.out.println(s));}
```

Surprised there wasn't a Java answer yet.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwFEV3vuKFqR3gBxqdXWRhNA7PUkyxvJL2gTGEb69FWW5yb3LuGXDByk@Ghu6VtMMY4YqW1gLAEpvQozbQ7BVg8bYDLVoOlp4QpcrrVuSIjGw1NEBwghSr89r7IJRqP5HNWPuZ6ykz7EhEKdWW1E5N88Nl6oB/52NWH/@3O6D8e6nWorwY5zy8fXBdeZi39AU) (Wait 60 second for it to time-out.)

Comment: you don't need to wait for it to timeout, it'll reach the max output buffer of 128kb much faster than that :P

Comment: @Mayube Perhaps, but it's still running `Real time: 60.008 s` according to the Debug-section before it outputs the result (and gives two warnings 60-sec limit exceeded and 128kb exceeded).

Comment: TIO also caches the results, so once it's been run and hit the timelimit, the output is cached and will simply be served to others who run it without actually re-compiling and running the code

Comment: @Mayube True. I didn't knew this also applied to others. Thought it was a local cache. In that case you can ignore the "_(Wait 60 second for it to time-out.)_" in my answer. :) But if you check on the "disable output cache" setting you'll see it takes ~ 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 27 bytes

```perl
while(1){print"$ARGV[0]\n"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/788IzMnVcNQs7qgKDOvREnFMcg9LNogNiZPqfb///8eqTk5@YoA)

Comment: input will always be given, it just might be an empty string, so you should be able to do `while(1){print"$ARGV[0]\n"}`

Comment: @Mayube - thx, updated answer.

Comment: Also welcome to ppcg! I fixed the formatting on your answer for you, in the future I totally recommend using Try it online (linked in the edited answer) as it not only makes testing way easier, but can give you a fully formatted ppcg answer to post

Comment: @Mayube - thx, glad to be here...

Answer (score 1):

### SAS, 32 bytes

```
%macro t(s);%put&s;%t(&s);%mend;
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 17 bytes

This one taking a reasonable position towards the shorter end of the non-golf-langs:

```
$f={for(){$args}}
```

The infinite recursion approach works, at least for a while, but isn't as terse:

```
$f={($s="$args");& $f $s}
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 45 bytes

```sql
CREATE PROC r @ TEXT=NULL AS G:PRINT @ GOTO G
```

Usage

```sql
EXECUTE r 'Hello word!'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

```
∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HHvP///yt5pObk5OsohOcX5aQoKgEA)

In Husk, `∞` builds an infinite list repeating its argument forever. If a full program produces a list of strings as result, they get printed by joining them with newlines.
The wonderful thing about Husk's laziness is that computations involving infinite lists can be managed and used to produce useful output, like in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-pn`, 2 bytes

```
{⑩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/@tHElf//e6Tm5OT/1y3IAwA)

Forever, print the top of the stack with a newline without popping it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
1W@;.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/98w3MFaz@H/f6W0/HwlAA)

Explanation:

```
1W@;.@  (implicit input)
1       push 1
 W      loop while top of stack is truthy:
  @       move input to top of stack
   ;.     duplicate and print
     @    move 1 to top of stack to continue loop
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 3 bytes

```
{?;
```

Explanation

```
{      DO
 ?     PRINT
  ;    a string read from the cmd line
       DO is implicitly closed by EOF
```

Comment: What on earth is QBIC in Google Drive for???

Comment: @MDXF 'cause I can't handle any other source control solution...

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 46 bytes

```
import."fmt"
func f(s string){for{Println(s)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxCgIxEET7fMWyVQISsLUTO6vrxWI5LuHQZI/dWIV8ey564FTDm8dE7hvNL4oLJFqzMWvaWAogK/67FllzVOwH8BhSQRM@eYZgFY7Z1cBSp1HLO1t1rfWf8b21rhoYGfZx5e88KKu/StTH@fI8AQI6Z1rvN1moLEAwkQgXmISjUNoB)

### Recursive approach, 46 bytes

Surprisingly, a recursive approach led to the same byte count.

```
import."fmt"
func f(s string){Println(s);f(s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxCgIxEET7fMWy1S1IwFYrsbNKLxbLkQuHJnvsxuq4b4/RA6eZ4c0wSdrC45NThMxzcW7Oi2gFFMN/tqpzSYZtBx6nXNFN7zLCNBjsNa2hW32VwejcMW3tt/jeDrQ66Op4v/I36VTMXzTZ/Xh6HAABidzW2lUj1wgMgVWlQlBJyvkD)

Comment: Avoid the `import."fmt"` by using the built-in `print` command: `func f(s string){for{print(s+"\n")}}`

Comment: @chowey That prints to STDERR, not STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 20

```
while 1 {puts $argv}
```

---

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMXREQnByV0hDckk) —  on the green area type

```
tclsh main.tcl string you want to repeat
```

where `string you want to repeat` is the input for program.

**DO NOT USE BACKSPACE KEY ON GREEN AREA!** It will make browser go back in history.

Answer (score 0):

## shortC, 7 bytes

```
AWJ@[1]
```

Explanation:

```
A        main function
 W       while loop
  J      print string with newline
   @[1]  first command line argument
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fMdzLIdow9v///54KBZkllQolGakKafn5AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 19+3 = 22 bytes

+3 for flag `-z`, which adds an infinite stream of `0x00` bytes to the end of the input.

```
cCGgbbBAa
fF^~^dDEe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/P9nZPT0pyckxkSvNLa4uLsXFNfX//4zUnJx8xf@6VQA)

The behavior, in pseudocode:

```
out_byte := in_byte
if !(in_byte & 0x60) {
    out_byte |= 0x0A
}
```

Basically, if both bits `0x20` and `0x40` are unset, then either we have a newline character, or we've hit the end of the input. In either case, we just output a newline character and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 8 bytes

```
>v
np
rk
```

Uses sticky mode to avoid having to duplicate the string.

Answer (score 0):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 12 bytes

```
5

4

11
6
2
```

Read a value into the 0th line, print the value in the 0th line, print a newline, then jump to line 2.

Answer (score 0):

## [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 9 bytes

```
i1=v
1`p>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otyUwuzUks@v8/09C2jMswocDu/3@P1JycfEUA)

### Explanation:

```
i1=        Sets variable 1's value to a single line of input read from STDIN
   v       Change direction to down
   >       Change direction to right, wrap from end of line
1`p        1` fetches the value of variable 1, p prints it
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 22 bytes

```
while 1:print(input())
```

Surprised not to have seen a python 3 answer yet.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This code won't work currently, as it will call `input()` each time, meaning it will only output the input once. I highly suggest using [TIO](http://tio.run/#python3) for testing and formatting your answer, it makes life much easier

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69EI1Hz/3@P1JycfEUA) is as short as one can get in python3, although I'm not great at python3 golfing, I usually golf in weird esoteric languages

Comment: @Mayube Ah, I misunderstood what was required.

Answer (score 0):

### Vim, 6 bytes

Similar solution as the `V` answer.

```
Yqqp@q
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
a=input()
while 1:print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69EI1Hz//88AA)

As simple as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 1 [byte](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

It's not an infinitely-repeating built-in. That will be explained in the explanation.

```
I
```

## Explanation

With implicit inputs this becomes:

````
aPI

  I % An infinite loop with the following body:
a   % Take a single input from the arguments
 P  % Implicitly print the inputted argument on every iteration
    % (The above printing only occurs if the operand expression)
    % hasn't been printed before
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [Hy](https://github.com/hylang/hy), 34 bytes

```
(setv a(input))(while 1(print a))
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y6j8/1@jOLWkTCFRIzOvoLREU1OjPCMzJ1XBUKOgKDOvRCFRU/P///L8ouxiAA)